# Worklight Disable password save

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Im trying to disable the "Do you want the browser to remember this password" popup of the webview,
I added the line

```
 this.appView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
```

In the onCreate, before the loadURL command.  But it does suppress the save password info feature.

ADDITION:

This is happening when the user submits their login information in the login form on my app:

```
<form onsubmit="dojo.byId('passwordLogin').blur();return false;">
            <input id="emailAddressLogin" type="email" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" placeholder="Email Address" value="" selectOnClick="true"></input>
            <input id="passwordLogin" type="password" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" placeholder="Password" value="" selectOnClick="true"></input>

            <br/>
            <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" type="submit" class="baseBtn navyBtn loginButton" onClick="processLoginAuthentication()">Login</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: How about some context to the question... where is this happening?

Comment: my app has a login form. one of the fields is type="password", it seems that this is triggering the webview's dialog to ask the user if they want to save the forms password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should work:

```
this.appView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
```